# Guice: the @Inject at static fields

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

Now I am reading the official documentation of PlayFramework, but it doesn't actually matter.

And I saw this sentence:

> Note that those are instance fields. It generally doesn’t make sense to inject a static field, since it would break encapsulation.

They explained it is deprecated to use `@Inject` annotation toward static fields.  Why?
I don't understand "break encapsulation".   What do you think they mean by the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda obvious OOP principle (encapsulation), so `@Inject` will provide an instance field (this is taken from Play documentation), then of course it will be strange to make it static, since **ALL** instances will share same object for field A, which is one of the possible problems and one of the definition of **breaking encapsulation**

> This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of
>   the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes
>   dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because stylistically

```
class Foo
{
  @Inject
  static String propery;
}
```

is equiavalent of

```
class Foo
{
  static String propery;

  Foo(String property) {
    this.property = property;
  }
}
```

those who do not know implementation details can be surprised by result